# Using Strptime When Some Data Has Microseconds & Some Does Not

Tags: python, datetime

I have a dataset with strings I am converting to DateTime. Unfortunately, some of the data has microseconds and some does not. When I attempt to transform the data using the following, I get the below error.

```
data['end_date'] = data['end_date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))    

ValueError: time data '2018-11-16 16:28:51' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
```

When I remove the .%f I get the following error.

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: .677215
```

Can someone help me with a simple way to make strptime smarter to handle these cases? I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
try:
    data['end_date'] = data['end_date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
except ValueError:
    data['end_date'] = data['end_date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, seeing the following:

    `ValueError: time data '2018-11-16 16:28:51' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    ValueError          ValueError: unconverted data remains: .677215`

Comment: Any other suggestions @thanhdattran? I am not sure why the throwing of an error is not being handled using the try / except.